# How to get Outlook event by organizer's email with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Here is the URL

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end&$top=100&$filter=organizer/emailAddress/address eq 'jhon@duo.com'`

this is Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnsupportedEntityExpression",
        "message": "'i => (i.Organizer.EmailAddress == \"hon@duo.com\")' is not a supported filter expression.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "04693e1d-b7aa-4361-9232-4287b1ae4",
            "date": "2018-10-18T10:09:46"
        }
    }
}
```

Please give me the solution

Answer (score 1):

Just as the exception message said, the query you use is not support:

> 'i => (i.Organizer.EmailAddress == \"hon@duo.com\")' is not a
>   supported filter expression

The temp solution/workaround for you is to query the list first and then do in-memory filter.

Meanwhile you can submit an feature request on the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).